# C: Pointer to a type of specified length

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm coding something in C and dealing with situations where it would be helpful to be able to say "cast this to a pointer pointing to a datatype with the same number of bytes as this number".

An example will make it clearer - I'm using `size_t` to get the size of a pointer on the system. Now I want to portably cast a `void *` pointer to a pointer to a datatype of that size. I know I could cast it to any pointer type and it would be the same length, but the pointer arithmetic differs depending on the datatype the variable is pointing to. Also, in my case `size_t` happens to be 8 bytes, and so does `double`, so I could just cast my `void *` to a `double *`, but I want a portable solution. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe explain what you're trying to achieve with this strange casting could help - there might be ways of doing what your actual goal is.

Comment: Use use `size_t` of `sizeof`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What wrong about `size_t*` (assuming I understood your question)

In the general case, where you need pointer to a type with `n` bytes, you can do:

```
void *voidptr=... //assign whatever you want.
char (*myptr)[n]=voidptr; //a pointer to char[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pointer to a type that is the same size as a pointer, why not use `void **`?